# Partial views and Conditional rendering Mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, refactoring, partial-views

I have started to refactor some project , and I've faced with some code that seems to be written wrong because of code duplication , but the problem that i dont know how to refactor this in best maneer. Of cource I can remove code duplication by extracting functions and clean some code, using generics but i think maybe i can do more than this. The story is :

We Have a page (view ) , That is rendering multiple partial views according to User Choise:
we have some linkes like :

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Create", "SetCreateNewMessageView")</br>
                    @Html.ActionLink("GetMessagesHistory", "SetGetMessagesHistoryView")</br>
                    @Html.ActionLink("UpdateMessageStatus", "SetUpdateMessageStatusView")</br>
                    @Html.ActionLink("AddUser", "SetAddUserView")</br>
                    @Html.ActionLink("RemoveUser", "SetRemoveUserView")</br>
```

Each click renders partial view in this way ->
Controller :

```
 var containModel = new CreatorsViewModel();
        containModel.CreateNewMessage = model;
        **containModel.view = 1;**
        return View("Index", containModel);
```

And that's made for each link  , then in Page's View the following conditional rendering is :

```
 @if (Model.view == 1)
                    { // Render Partial view
```

}

Is there some best practices in my case (Rendering different partial views according to user choise) or it will be enogh just to remove code duplication ?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of one try to use enum, rest is fine with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, conditional rendering is a common thing in MVC. The only change I'd make is to convert your `if` statements to be a `switch`, just to tidy things up a bit (that's assuming you have `if`, `else if`, `else if` etc. for multiple Model values).